# Netcore 2.2 - Docker Container cannot sending mail

Tags: c#, docker, email

i'm current deploy one application into docker container, this app have function sending mail
(base on c# netcore 2.2)
but i can not sending mail (while mean i can sending mail from localhost)
the message of exception in docker

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: GSSAPI operation failed with
>   error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
>   information (Cannot find KDC for realm "xxx.yyyy").    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String
>   package, Boolean isServer, NetworkCredential credential)    at
>   System.Net.NTAuthentication.Initialize(Boolean isServer, String
>   package, NetworkCredential credential, String spn, ContextFlagsPal
>   requestedContextFlags, ChannelBinding channelBinding)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String
>   challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String
>   spn, ChannelBinding channelBindingToken)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.SetContextAndTryAuthenticate(ISmtpAuthenticationModule
>   module, NetworkCredential credential, ContextAwareResult context)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32
>   port)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host,
>   Int32 port)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

i have try some help from google but can not, so please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue in dotnet on linux, when you send mails with the GSSAPI authentication type:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2174, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25885, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27285

Try installing "gss-ntlmssp" in the container if you need to use GSSAPI.

Or, if your server accepts other authentication types, use another one, like NTLM:

```
var cred = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(host, 25, "NTLM", cred);
client.Credentials = cache;
```